# Add class name for generated Html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is html part

```
<li class="main_menu catagory_li" id="cat4">
    <p class="ahead"><span class="heading">Item 4</span>
    <span class="fright remove">close</span></p>
</li>
```

when i click `close` i copy the `LI` using below code,

```
$('.remove').live('click',function(){
    var closed_elem_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

        s = $(this).parent().parent().clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
        $('li#'+closed_elem_id).remove();
        console.log(s);

});
```

This one removes the `LI` in particular place and get the copy and store it in `variable s`.

My requirement is to add class called no-display in cloned copy like `<span class="fright remove no-display">close</span>` . I tried this many ways but it fails.

Kindly advice on this

NOTE : updated my question

Comment: You're using `parent()` twice. Are you trying to select the parent `li`?

Comment: @Purmou Yes I get complete LI part.when i click close, need to add class name in close class

Comment: Did you try .addClass() immediately after .clone()? What is the .each() loop for?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, that each function is no needed, forgot to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little optimized: http://jsfiddle.net/hKUd6/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.remove').live('click',function(){
    var pLi = $(this).closest('li');
    s = $('<div>').append(pLi.clone().addClass('no-display')).html();
    pLi.remove();
    console.log(s);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing is very sloppy. You don't need to use as much code as you have to accomplish the simple task you're attempting.

Try something like this:

```
$("li").on("click", ".remove", function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        liCont = $this.closest("p"),
        parentLi = $this.closest("li");
    liCont
        .clone()
        .wrap(
            $("<div>").addClass("no-display")
        )
        .appendTo("body");
    parentLi.remove();
});
```

What we do here is capture the click event on any `.remove` elements. We select the parent `p` (which we later clone to wrap with a `div`) as well as the parent `li`. We clone the `p` element (including its contents), wrap it with a `div` element (which we create using DOM scripting and add the class), and append the finished product to the body (you can change that if needed). We then remove the original `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, it should work:

```
$('.remove').live('click',function(){
    var closed_elem = $(this).closest("li"); //get the li to be closed/removed
    var clonedElem = closed_elem.clone().find("span.remove").addClass("no-display"); //clone the original li and add the no-display class to the span having remove class
    closed_elem.remove(); //remove the original li
    console.log(clonedElem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below lines of code.

first of all you need to get current class name using jquery:

```
$('li #cat4').find('span').each(function(){
  var classname = $(this).attr('class');
  $(this).addClass(classname+' no-display');
});
```

This is not a complete code of your task, but its just a code by which you can get a current class and then add more required string to it and set new class.

Thanks.